# Integrals: can we take limits ‘partially’?

Tags: integration, limits

Suppose I have an integral that converges properly
$$\int^b_a f(t)dt$$ where $f(t)$ is a complex analytic function.

($a,b\in\mathbb R, b>a$).

The integral is taken on a straight path.

I applied a substitution $u=\frac1{t-a+\frac1R}$, then we have the original integral equals to 
$$\int^R_{\frac1{b-a+\frac1R}}\frac{f(\frac1u+a-\frac1R)}{u^2}du$$

My question is, under what conditions is this true?

> $$\int^b_a f(t)dt=\lim_{R\to\infty} \int^R_{\frac1{b-a+\frac1R}}\frac{f(\frac1u+a-\frac1R)}{u^2}du =\lim_{R\to\infty} \int^R_{\frac1{b-a}}\frac{f(\frac1u+a)}{u^2}du$$

I apologize for not being able to provide much context, as I have no idea how to tackle this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the change of variables we already have for any $R \in (0,\infty)$

$$\int^R_{\frac1{b-a+\frac1R}}\frac{f(\frac1u+a-\frac1R)}{u^2}du = \int^b_a f(t)dt,$$

so

$$\lim_{R \to \infty}\int^R_{\frac1{b-a+\frac1R}}\frac{f(\frac1u+a-\frac1R)}{u^2}du = \int^b_a f(t)dt,$$

since for all $\epsilon > 0$, regardless of $R$,

$$\left|\int^R_{\frac1{b-a+\frac1R}}\frac{f(\frac1u+a-\frac1R)}{u^2}du - \int^b_a f(t)dt\right| = 0 < \epsilon$$

This is not entirely trivial in that the validity of change-of-variables has some conditions. However, integrability of $f$ and monotonicity of $u \mapsto 1/u +a - 1/R$ is sufficient.

For the second part apply the variable change $t = 1/u +a$ first to the integral over $[a + 1/R,b]$ to get

$$\int_{a + 1/R}^b f(t) \, dt = \int^R_{\frac1{b-a}}\frac{f(\frac1u+a)}{u^2}du.$$

We always have $\lim_{c \to a+}\int_c^b f(t) \, dt = \int_a^bf(t) \, dt$ if $f$ is properly integrable. Hence,

$$\int_a^b f(t) \, dt = \lim_{R \to \infty} \int_{a + 1/R}^b f(t) \, dt = \lim_{R \to \infty} \int^R_{\frac1{b-a}}\frac{f(\frac1u+a)}{u^2}du$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it is not complete yet because there are two equalities in the yellow box. Could you please also prove the second equality?

Comment: @Szeto: Sure -- that can be done.

Comment: Tons of thanks to you!

Comment: @Szeto: You're welcome.  A most unusual question!